# How can I influence the data type of a MariaDB Sequence?

Tags: mariadb

I want the return value of a sequence to be of type INT. I created a sequence with MINVALUE and MAXVALUE within the value range of INT:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_NAME 
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE = 1
    MAXVALUE = 2147483647;
```

But I still get BIGINT back if I use

`SELECT NEXTVAL(SEQ_NAME)`

Comment: In many situations, the specific int type should matter.  Please elaborate on how it is giving you a problem.

Comment: It is not a drastic problem, I can also work with BIGINT. I am rather curious if this is possible because I definitely won't need the extra space.

Comment: I _suspect_ that a `Sequence` is implemented as a single 8 byte (bigint) value stored on disk somewhere.  (Or perhaps, 3 bigints -- increment, min, max)  The disk space is probably one "block"; nothing would be saved by the added complexity of having the numbers stored as `INT` or some other datatype.